# Angular/Visual Studio Code -error on 'export class name'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Strange behavior in visual studio code today.

1. I Created new project "ng new myproject" - pure vanilla
2. server finds no issues (ng serve -o), Browser seems happy with results
3. load in Visual studio Code 1.33.1. Edit file (just add a space), save,
   Visual Studio finds errors exporting class. (see below)
4. Repeated with new project name. Same issue.
5. Yesterday's project loads without issue
6. Can build (ng build --prod) - also no issues
7. re-installed new version of VS Code. Same issues.
8. Tried: "experimentalDecorators" : true in tsconfig.app.json

Where to look next?

[image]

Edit:
Error message:
Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.ts(1219)

Probably generic message.

Comment: hover over the redline and mention the error what error does it shows

Comment: "Probably generic message." NOPE. I encourage you to search and learn more about that error. The block above the export statement is a decorator (`@Component()`).

Comment: True enough. But this is pure generic code generated by "ng new myproject".  Tried adding : "experimentalDecorators" : true in tsconfig.app.json...  Same issue.

Comment: I doubt the error suggests the right fix, but it probably suggests what went wrong with the project or workspace. Finding other cases might lead you to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Changed path reference in workspace definition from "src" to dot.
Seems to be better now.

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Found this Error

In VSCode go to **preferences** -> **settings**, you will see an option to enable/disable **experimentalDecorators**. Check it and save the settings file. Done